# Turn off results in PROC IML in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-iml

We can turn off/on the results by doing

> ods noresults;
>   ods results;

However, if you are within PROC IML, and you write that, you are sent out of the procedure, and you have to repeat all again. How do avoid that, i.e. how to turn on/off the results without exiting PROC IML?

I added captures that show Proc IML running and then turned off when I do ODS RESULTS.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The ODS statement is a global statement. It does not make procedures exit.

Are you running your example in SAS Enterprise Guide? EG automatically appends a QUIT to every program, which causes interactive procedures to exit. The solution is to run your program in the SAS Windowing Envirnoment ("display manager") or some other non-EG envrionment.

Comment: No, I am using SAS Base

Comment: @Rick I added pictures

Comment: try using the `NOPRINTALL` or `NOPRINT` options in the `proc iml` statement

Comment: I've never seen this before.  It doesn't happen for me at SAS 9.3 or SAS 9.4 on Windows.  Contact SAS Technical Support and give them details like your SAS version, OS, etc.

Comment: You also might clarify why you _want_ to do this.  Even if there is some reason this is the case in your system (and I agree with Rick that it shouldn't), there may be a way to do what you want differently.